# how to stop AVAudioPlayer securely

Tags: iphone, crash, release, avaudioplayer

i have an AVAudioPlayer with two buttons : Play and Stop.
The play button is hidden when playing, and vice versa.

The problem is that a crash occurs when i attempt to push the Stop button, just at the end of the playing, at the moment when the method "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" is invoked.
Indeed, this method release the AVAudioPlayer, and when i push the stop button (which release the object too...) it crashes.
But still, i test if the player is nil before releasing it manually, so why does it crashes and how to avoid this ?

My code :
in the .h :

```
@private AVAudioPlayer* monPlayer;
```

in the .m :

```
-(IBAction)playSound{
NSString *path = nil;
if(path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sounds/%d", idoiseau]  ofType:@"m4a"])
    {
    monPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    monPlayer.delegate = self;
    [monPlayer play];
    [buttonPlay setEnabled:NO];
    [buttonStop setEnabled:YES];
    }
else return; 
}

-(IBAction)stopSound{
if(!monPlayer) return;
[monPlayer stop];
[monPlayer release]; 
monPlayer = nil;
[buttonPlay setEnabled:YES];
[buttonStop setEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
[player release];
player = nil;
    [buttonPlay setEnabled:YES];
[buttonStop setEnabled:NO];
}
```

edit : just replace the local variable "player" by the instance variable "monPlayer" in the delegate method, and it works. Thanks to hotpaw2 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be setting the local parameter player to nil instead of the object instance variable monPlayer.

Comment: Ho ho... you're perfectly right : Now it works, by replacing the local variable by the instance variable. Thank you !